# What could be causing selection to be missing activeGameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am getting the following error trying to build an editor window in Unity 2019.3.14f:

```
Assets\Editor\CellViewer.cs(19,40): error CS0117: 'Selection' does not contain a definition for 'activeGameObject'
```

I have found evidence of a single person with this specific error on the unity answer board, but there are no answers or updates in 5 years. I have reloaded the project, restarted unity, and restarted my system multiple times since this error first appeared.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class CellViewer : EditorWindow
{
    private Map map;

    [MenuItem ("Window/Cell Viewer")]
    public static void ShowWindow() {
        EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(CellViewer));
    }

    void OnGUI () {
        
        if(Map.isInstanceActive())
        {
            GameObject obj = Selection.activeGameObject;
            Tile tile = obj.GetComponent<Tile>();
            if(tile != null) {
                map = Map.Instance();
                loadCell(map.getCell(tile.coordinates)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could this have happened, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Is it possible you have another class in your project named `Selection`? 
You can make sure it's using the correct selection class by saying `GameObject obj = UnityEditor.Selection.activeGameObject`

Comment: @Molly_J Yes! That is the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the classname `Selection` is ambiguous because you've created a class by that name in the global namespace.

To make sure you're using the correct one you can have your code be explicit by adding:
`GameObject obj = UnityEditor.Selection.activeGameObject`